# PHP code to decrypt XML encrypted through Java

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to decrypt XML which is enrypted through Java but no luck...
I have tried functions like mcrypt_decrypt and also followed other posts but I am not sure what exact parameters to pass.

Can someone please help me to create PHP function to decrypt this.
I have the java code which is encrypting the XML.

```
private static String encrypt(String encryptionKey, String value) throws Exception{

    //Instantiate the encrypter/decrypter
    String paddedValue = value;
    if ((value.length() % 8) != 0) {
        for (int i= 0; i< (8 - value.length() % 8); i++) {
            paddedValue += ' ';
        }
    }             

    byte[] iv ={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    byte[] valueByteArray = paddedValue.getBytes("UTF8");

    SecretKeySpec desKey = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes(), "DES");
    Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8        
    // Encrypt
    byte[] encryptedBytesArray = desCipher.doFinal(valueByteArray);

    StringBuffer encryptedValue = new StringBuffer(1000000);

    for (int i = 0, n = encryptedBytesArray.length; i < n; i++) {
        String hex = (java.lang.Integer.toHexString(encryptedBytesArray[i] & 0XFF));
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            encryptedValue.append("0").append(hex);
        } else {
            encryptedValue.append(hex);
        }
    }

    return encryptedValue.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the last PHP code you have tried? And perhaps it might be a good idea to share the encrypted and decrypted XML as well.

Comment: `mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, hex2bin($data), "cbc")` should do the trick, though.

Comment: @Jack I am using PHP code


$result=mcrypt_decrypt ( "MCRYPT_3DES" , 'secTotal' , $data , 'cbc');
echo $result;

Comment: hex2bin is available with PHP5.4, let me update it quickly and I will update you on it.
Thanks Jack

Comment: Hi Jack, many thanks for your help. your code worked very fine with PHP 5.4 and plus.... just trying to find alternative for hx2bin for php 5.3. I will post here if I find any. 
Once again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mcrypt_decrypt()`](http://php.net/mcrypt_decrypt), using the following arguments:

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, hex2bin($data), "cbc");
```

If you don't have [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/hex2bin) you can use [`pack()`](http://php.net/pack):

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, pack('H*', $data), "cbc");
```

Comment: pack() returns some weird output as follows


9¹µÕ¾Q¨õ¹&¦ÒZøû¥±S'/ßNnªEfS²®MCK–^N ¿žhü ½èûáŠc……&Ë³Sþ&”,"@"í¼‰(¬ç ßLÌHE–qa¥b¸ëE“”hÑ n´`á¤#üÛ9™ØºË1ˆóµŸFžéz51~/y4'›6]ƒ‹ðã]÷%£¼K¸àºÃ>ó0§åÊÖ9ñŸÔ`Føã¨.›FÓ¼ñ8 v~Þý‚ó(x-'YÓ÷V û‹[Ÿc™ˆjM"3EŽ Íì!Äßwýâ"WL—½Â¦Ø9Ï(#üEý¨R) |‡óý:Ì˜p‡ß‘‹ÔçüèÉU/ÓâÈ­•7ˆK|YhelôpÐ#.®WÍÛózg‚V¦?sV…µõŠ¤ƒ4pt%í<õó©V"Ú#Ò5Wr±!²Ú­$mâá¾âî¥û nf˜‚ž˜]L$ JîÕ¤5~C]0¢Hsá¨6hðãÅˆÈÈwô»¡¡ý uyƒ•A·2ÞÔáKp¹çpw™/w¤§%àú}¸ÆDÌÂ•Îº;ÆÉþ-ƒÒvzþK„ ó›áä“?XNÀ´R~•a!oÄ?ÿT=IÞS»

Comment: Well, it should be a proper replacement for `hex2bin()`.