# PHP code to encrypt XMLwhich will be decrypted over Java

Tags: java, php, xml, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt XML using PHP which will be decrypted over java.
While I am doing R&D and i found a code over this link [PHP code to decrypt XML encrypted through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654565/php-code-to-decrypt-xml-encrypted-through-java) which is doing exactly opposite thing that I am looking for. How can I encrypt XML which comfortably decrypted over java?

Comment: Try something. That other question should have been more than enough of a starting point. Read the docs. Learn the API. Don't expect a copy & paste answer for every single thing you ever need to develop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to decript a file with diferent language. You just have to implement the same encrypter algorithm and that it's. If you want an asymetric encrypt take a look for RSA, if you want a symetric one look for DES.

Ans sorry but it's all informations you will take on the thread. This site is not a "code on demand" site.